# Qt 4.8.1 Postgres Psql driver not loaded (Windows7 64bit)

Tags: qt, windows-7, psql

I cannot Debug with the old Qt 4.8.0 psql driver. And the new Qt 4.8.1 psql driver cannot be loaded..

```
[ListAvailableSQLDrivers : [0mPluginsPath() C:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2010\plugins
[ListAvailableSQLDrivers : [0mQSqlDatabase::drivers() QSQLITE
[ListAvailableSQLDrivers : [0mQSqlDatabase::drivers() QODBC3
[ListAvailableSQLDrivers : [0mQSqlDatabase::drivers() QODBC
```

I'm working with QtSDK 1.2 (Qt 4.8.1), Win7 64bit and PgAdmin 1.14.3

My QT c++ software can load the old psql driver from Qt 4.8.0:

*C:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2010\plugins\sqldrivers*,
**qsqlpsql4.dll,
qsqlpsql4d.dll**

I've tried to compile the psql driver from the Qt Sources. That worked partially. On my laptop, the compiled driver cannot be loaded, but on the laptops of my buddies this driver is working. We all have Win7 64bit. Any ideas how to track this down are welcomed.

thanx QtDeveloper

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend not to mix Qt-dlls of one computer with plugins built/installed on another.
Qt stores default paths of plugins in Qt-dlls and the paths provided during compilation/installation on different computers may differ.

Try to use procmon from sysinternals, and see during the start of the process which paths the app tries to open while seatching for the plugins.

Try to copy \plugins\sqldrivers* to  `<YourAppStartPath>\plugins\sqldrivers`